# Object Method returns the code as a string

Tags: javascript

I've just started to learn javascript and can't seem to call an object method properly. I've even copy pasted the code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp) to try to understand my mistake but it just returns the code as a string. My code:

```js
function greetings(name){
    document.getElementById('someText').innerHTML = 'Hello' + ' ' + name;
}

const person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: 5566,
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
  

  greetings(person.fullName);
```

```html
<div id="someText"></div>
```

And the result:

> Hello function() { return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; }

Comment: `person.fullName` to `person.fullName()` (At the end)

Comment: On the [JavaScript Object Methods page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp) you posted, if you scroll down just a tiny bit, it gives the example usage `name = person.fullName();` and then says ___If you access the `fullName` property, without `()`, it will return the function definition:___ and has your example of `name = person.fullName;`.  There's even a "Try it yourself" button. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the method, which will return a string of the person's name, and then that will be passed to the greetings function.
Without the `()` the method is not executed and the method itself is passed to the greetings function.
Since it is treated as a string in the function you get the toString() method being called on the function which results in the function code itself.

```js
function greetings(name){
    document.getElementById('someText').innerHTML = 'Hello' + ' ' + name;
}

const person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    id: 5566,
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
  

  greetings(person.fullName());
  console.log(person.fullName.toString());
```

```html
<div id="someText"></div>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

since you defined `fullname` as a function here:

```
fullName: function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

then you have to **call** it, like: `greetings(person.fullName());` with the additional brackets at the end

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem in two ways.

```
//firstly

 greetings(person.fullName()); // calling the function when you pass it as a Arguments. 

// secondly
function greetings(name){
    document.getElementById('someText').innerHTML = 'Hello' + ' ' + name();
// if you always except a function as a peramiter just call it when you use it.
}
```

you define fullName as a person object property which is a function. For getting the proper value you have to call the function. we used () after the function name for calling it. if the function didn't call it returns the function body.